# Problemas con PHP al ejecutar consulta mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Cada vez que intento grabar datos en una base de datos me aparece el siguiente error;

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ejercicios\Taller_3_insertar.php on line 10

Este el código:

```
<?php 

    include("Conexion_Taller3.php");
    if (isset($_POST["nombre"]) && !empty($_POST["nombre"]) && isset($_POST["pw"]) && !empty($_POST["pw"])) 
    {

        echo " **************";
        $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw) or die ("problemas al conectar");
        mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die ("Problemas al conectar con la base de datos");
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO alumnos(NOMBRE,PW) VALUES ("$_POST["nombre"]","$_POST["pw"]")",$con);
        echo "Datos insertados";

    }

    else
    {

        echo "Problemas al insertar datos *********************";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estas teniendo problemas con el uso de Comillas entonces yo haría esto

Primero asigno a variables los valores que llegan por POST así

```
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$pw = $_POST['pw'];
```

Posterior pasa dichas variables a tu consulta de este modo

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO alumnos(NOMBRE,PW) VALUES ('".$nombre."', '".$pw."')",$con);
```

Acomodando las variables entre el juego de Comillas simple doble y terminando con comilla doble y simple, quedando tu código así:

```
<?php 

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$pw = $_POST['pw'];

 include("Conexion_Taller3.php");
    if (isset($nombre) && !empty($nombre) && isset($pw) && !empty($pw)) 
    {
        echo " **************";
        $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw) or die ("problemas al conectar");
        mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die ("Problemas al conectar con la base de datos");
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO alumnos(NOMBRE,PW) VALUES ('".$nombre."', '".$pw."')",$con);
        echo "Datos insertados";
    }else{
        echo "Problemas al insertar datos *********************";
    }
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Con el driver `mysqli` la estructura de la consulta pudiera quedar así:

```
<?php 

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$pw = $_POST['pw'];

    if (isset($nombre) && !empty($nombre) && isset($pw) && !empty($pw)) 
    {
        echo " **************";
        $conexion = new mysqli("servidor", "usuario", "contrasenia", "basedatos");
        $consulta = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO alumnos(NOMBRE,PW) VALUES (?, ?)");
        $consulta->bind_param("ss", $nombre, $pw);
        $consulta->execute();
    }else{
        echo "Problemas al insertar datos *********************";
    }
```

**Explicación**

- En la instancia la clase `mysqli` pasas tus credenciales de acceso a tu gestor de bases de datos
- En el método `prepare()` pasa las columnas a rellenar y en lugar de las variables directas usa marcadores de posición con `?`
- Usa el método `bind_param()` para pasar los tipos de datos `s` es para `string` y posterior separados por comas las variables a interpolar
- Finalmente ejecuta la consulta con `execute()`

**Observaciones**

- Usas una versión obsoleta del driver MySQL para conectarte, considera migrar a PDO o MySQLi
- En la medida que el proyecto lo permita deberías usar sentencias preparadas
- [mysqli driver](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Haciendo el cambio que me dices me sale el siguiente error:

Comment: Error fatal : Error no detectado: Llamada a la función indefinida mysql_connect () en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ Ejercicios \ Taller_3_insertar.php: 10 Stack trace: # 0 {main} arrojado en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ Ejercicios \ Taller_3_insertar.php en la línea 10

Comment: el error en cuestión @Jav no tiene que ver directamente con mi respuesta, sino por que entonces estas en una versión de PHP que ya no soporta el uso de la extensión `mysql` lo cual indica que deberás migrar a mysqli o PDO como te recomiendo

Comment: vale, muchas gracias

Comment: actualizaré agregando como debería ser tu consulta con mysqli y aparte dejaré un enlace a la doc. oficial para que consultes mas del tema @Jav

Answer (score 1):

Prueba el codigo cambiando esta linea:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO alumnos(NOMBRE,PW) VALUES ("$_POST["nombre"]","$_POST["pw"]")",$con);
```

por esta otra:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO alumnos(NOMBRE,PW) VALUES (" . $_POST["nombre"] . "," . $_POST["pw"] .")",$con);
```